# How do I rigorously prove that the following series diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let

$a_n=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 & \frac{1}{n^2}, n \text{ is not a product of 3} & \\ 
 & -\frac{1}{n}, n \text{ is a product of 3} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Does $\sum a_n$ converge or diverge?

Obviously, I know that this series must diverge since the negative term will obviously dominate the positive terms eventually (which, we know, will converge to a number lesser than $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$). Is it possible to offer a rigorous proof, however?

Comment: The sum of the ${1 \over n^2}$ will converge, so you can focus on the other terms. Note that the remaining terms are of the form $-{1 \over 3} {1 \over n}$, so what happens when you sum them?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n =\sum _{p=1}^\infty\bigg[  \frac 1{(3p-2)^2 }+  \frac 1{(3p-1)^2} -  \frac 1{3p} \bigg]  $$

$$<\sum _{p=1}^\infty\bigg[  \frac 2{9p^2 }-  \frac 1{3p} \bigg] $$

whenever $p \ge 1$ we have that $\frac 2{9p^2 } <  \frac 1{4p}$

so
$$\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n < -\frac 1{12}\sum _{p=1}^\infty \frac 1p  $$

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge, then so does $\sum c_n$ where $c_n = a_n + b_n$ (1).

In your problem, let MY $a_n$ be $\frac{1}{n^2}$ if $n$ is not  a product of $3$, and $0$ otherwise, let $b_n$ be the $\frac{-1}{n}$ part, and let MY $c_n$ be your $a_n$.

On the one hand, you know that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges (to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but you don't need to know that), so because $0 \leq a_n \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$, you know that $\sum a_n$ converges (2).

On the other hand, you know that $\sum b_n = \frac{-1}{3}\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges (3).

Now, if $\sum c_n$ did converge, then by (1) and (2), and by rewriting $b_n = c_n + (-a_n)$, we would get that $\sum b_n$ converges, contradicting (3).